# Finding correct package versions using standalone Python 2.7 and Anaconda/Python 3.5 on same computer (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I have been using Python 2.7 for some time on this machine; I needed to install the Anaconda distribution with Python 3.5 for a team project.

I successfully installed Python 3.5, and now `python` points to Python 3.5, but when I try `import numpy`, my system goes looking for numpy in the place where my packages for 2.7 are located:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyBuffer_Type
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
```

I've tried adding `~/anaconda/pkgs` to my `PYTHONPATH` variable ahead of `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, but this doesn't seem to help. Though my focus is on getting things to work in 3.5, I'd like to be able to use both Python 2.7 and 3.5, so I don't want to uninstall 2.7 or completely remove the pointer to that version's package location.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you have the proper path for the anaconda installation. Then add ' ~//bin' to your PYTHONPATH instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try `unset PYTHONPATH`. It worked for me.